# How to PHP USORT based on date and time?

Tags: php

There is PHP array which I want to sort it date and time wise but things not working as expected. How can I sort this array according to incrementing date and time wise?

Original Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 44
            [Create_date] => 2018-07-07
            [Create_time] => 19:00:56
            [Invoice_series] => RR
            [Invoice_id] => 9
            [Amount] => 9402
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 46
            [Create_date] => 2018-07-09
            [Create_time] => 16:13:36
            [Invoice_series] => RR
            [Invoice_id] => 10
            [Amount] => 598
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 47
            [Create_date] => 2018-07-10
            [Create_time] => 16:52:22
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 5
            [Amount] => 10000
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 48
            [Create_date] => 2018-07-10
            [Create_time] => 16:59:32
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 6
            [Amount] => 16757
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 76
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-01
            [Create_time] => 11:44:20
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 14
            [Amount] => 1799
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 77
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-01
            [Create_time] => 18:41:00
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 15
            [Amount] => 1213
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 78
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-01
            [Create_time] => 18:44:08
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 16
            [Amount] => 19656
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 89
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-04
            [Create_time] => 10:02:50
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 17
            [Amount] => 10251
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 94
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-22
            [Create_time] => 14:58:22
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 21
            [Amount] => 9251
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 97
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-24
            [Create_time] => 11:47:51
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 22
            [Amount] => 5000
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 98
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-24
            [Create_time] => 15:02:05
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 23
            [Amount] => 5000
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 109
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-26
            [Create_time] => 18:26:13
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 24
            [Amount] => 10251
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 9
            [Create_date] => 2018-07-28
            [Create_time] => 15:10:33
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 1
            [Amount] => 1237
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 10
            [Create_date] => 2018-09-17
            [Create_time] => 15:43:30
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 2
            [Amount] => 361
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 13
            [Create_date] => 2018-09-18
            [Create_time] => 10:04:38
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 3
            [Amount] => 4307
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 14
            [Create_date] => 2018-09-18
            [Create_time] => 10:06:52
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 4
            [Amount] => 6262
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 15
            [Create_date] => 2018-09-29
            [Create_time] => 17:02:39
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 5
            [Amount] => 2253
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 18
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-12
            [Create_time] => 11:14:34
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 6
            [Amount] => 3186
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 29
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-24
            [Create_time] => 19:44:03
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 7
            [Amount] => 5000
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 30
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-25
            [Create_time] => 16:52:29
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 8
            [Amount] => 10251
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 50
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-26
            [Create_time] => 12:00:51
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 9
            [Amount] => 5000
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 51
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-26
            [Create_time] => 15:25:36
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 10
            [Amount] => 5000
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 52
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-27
            [Create_time] => 18:14:15
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 11
            [Amount] => 10251
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1018
            [Create_date] => 2018-11-23
            [Create_time] => 16:08:17
            [Payment_series] => RecT
            [Payment_id] => 2
            [Amount] => -20251
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => payment
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1020
            [Create_date] => 2018-11-23
            [Create_time] => 17:30:14
            [Payment_series] => RecT
            [Payment_id] => 3
            [Amount] => 9251
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => payment
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1021
            [Create_date] => 2018-11-23
            [Create_time] => 17:30:33
            [Payment_series] => RecT
            [Payment_id] => 4
            [Amount] => 0
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => payment
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1016
            [Create_date] => 2018-11-23
            [Create_time] => 11:28:57
            [Payment_series] => RecT
            [Payment_id] => 1
            [Amount] => 20251
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => payment
        )

)
```

USORT Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 44
            [Create_date] => 2018-07-07
            [Create_time] => 19:00:56
            [Invoice_series] => RR
            [Invoice_id] => 9
            [Amount] => 9402
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 46
            [Create_date] => 2018-07-09
            [Create_time] => 16:13:36
            [Invoice_series] => RR
            [Invoice_id] => 10
            [Amount] => 598
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 47
            [Create_date] => 2018-07-10
            [Create_time] => 16:52:22
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 5
            [Amount] => 10000
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 48
            [Create_date] => 2018-07-10
            [Create_time] => 16:59:32
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 6
            [Amount] => 16757
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 9
            [Create_date] => 2018-07-28
            [Create_time] => 15:10:33
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 1
            [Amount] => 1237
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 10
            [Create_date] => 2018-09-17
            [Create_time] => 15:43:30
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 2
            [Amount] => 361
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 14
            [Create_date] => 2018-09-18
            [Create_time] => 10:06:52
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 4
            [Amount] => 6262
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 13
            [Create_date] => 2018-09-18
            [Create_time] => 10:04:38
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 3
            [Amount] => 4307
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 15
            [Create_date] => 2018-09-29
            [Create_time] => 17:02:39
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 5
            [Amount] => 2253
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 76
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-01
            [Create_time] => 11:44:20
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 14
            [Amount] => 1799
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 78
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-01
            [Create_time] => 18:44:08
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 16
            [Amount] => 19656
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 77
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-01
            [Create_time] => 18:41:00
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 15
            [Amount] => 1213
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 89
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-04
            [Create_time] => 10:02:50
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 17
            [Amount] => 10251
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 18
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-12
            [Create_time] => 11:14:34
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 6
            [Amount] => 3186
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 94
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-22
            [Create_time] => 14:58:22
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 21
            [Amount] => 9251
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 29
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-24
            [Create_time] => 19:44:03
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 7
            [Amount] => 5000
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 97
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-24
            [Create_time] => 11:47:51
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 22
            [Amount] => 5000
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 98
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-24
            [Create_time] => 15:02:05
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 23
            [Amount] => 5000
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 30
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-25
            [Create_time] => 16:52:29
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 8
            [Amount] => 10251
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 51
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-26
            [Create_time] => 15:25:36
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 10
            [Amount] => 5000
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 109
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-26
            [Create_time] => 18:26:13
            [Invoice_series] => VS
            [Invoice_id] => 24
            [Amount] => 10251
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => Sale
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 50
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-26
            [Create_time] => 12:00:51
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 9
            [Amount] => 5000
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 52
            [Create_date] => 2018-10-27
            [Create_time] => 18:14:15
            [Invoice_series] => SRT
            [Invoice_id] => 11
            [Amount] => 10251
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => sale_return
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1020
            [Create_date] => 2018-11-23
            [Create_time] => 17:30:14
            [Payment_series] => RecT
            [Payment_id] => 3
            [Amount] => 9251
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => payment
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1021
            [Create_date] => 2018-11-23
            [Create_time] => 17:30:33
            [Payment_series] => RecT
            [Payment_id] => 4
            [Amount] => 0
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => payment
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1016
            [Create_date] => 2018-11-23
            [Create_time] => 11:28:57
            [Payment_series] => RecT
            [Payment_id] => 1
            [Amount] => 20251
            [Type] => Credit
            [Method] => payment
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1018
            [Create_date] => 2018-11-23
            [Create_time] => 16:08:17
            [Payment_series] => RecT
            [Payment_id] => 2
            [Amount] => -20251
            [Type] => Debit
            [Method] => payment
        )

)
```

PHP Code:

Sorted Time wise

```
usort($Ledgers, function( $a, $b ) {return strtotime($a["Create_time"]) - strtotime($b["Create_time"]);});
```

Sorted Date wise

```
usort($Ledgers, function( $a, $b ) {return strtotime($a["Create_date"]) - strtotime($b["Create_date"]);});
```

Answer (score 0):

you just concatenate date and time first

```
usort($Ledgers, function( $a, $b ) {
    $create_a = strtotime($a["Create_date"].$a["Create_time"]);
    $create_b = strtotime($b["Create_date"].$b["Create_time"]);
    return $create_a - $create_b;
});
```

and use usort function once.

---

and also another solution use `strcmp` to sort string

```
usort($Ledgers, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['Create_date'].$a['Create_time'], $b['Create_date'].$b['Create_time']);
});
```

Comment: You might want a space between the date and the time... also you can just `return $create_a - $create_b;`

Comment: i try to use space and without space. i get same result

Comment: Interesting - I wouldn't have expected `strtotime` to parse the string with no space between date and time.